# Center DIV in viewport when page is zoomed in

Tags: html, css

See that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZgxN/).
If you zoom in the page you'll see the first div is always visible and centered(width in %). The other one is not(width in px).
Can I somehow make the second div behave in a similar way?

Update:
The goal is to have it in the center. Its expanding beyond viewport borders is not a problem.

Btw: IE8 zooms in any website just as I need(Ok ok, I know that top left corner is more important).

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks logic. If you zoom in on an element whose size is fixed, it's going to get bigger, obviously. On the other hand, if you zoom in on an element with dynamic size, its size will adjust to the new viewport.

Comment: you're right the div will get bigger, but he wants the div in the middle.

Comment: Looks centred to me. Unless it gets wider than the viewport in which case it has no choice but to expand to the right. Unless they invented the negative scroll position while I wasn't looking.